# Networking.service takes 5 minutes after uninstalling network-manager

Tags: boot, networking, 17.04, services

I tried the [Solution here](https://askubuntu.com/a/848765/587552) to no avail, using `sudo systemctl edit networking.service` and adding TimeoutStartSec=10sec. But `sudo systemd-analyze blame` still puts networking.service at over 5 minutes. I checked the change after boot and the networking.service file still has the timeout in it. Can I just get rid of `networking.service` altogether since I use `ifup`?

`sudo systemctl status networking.service` gives:

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Tue 2017-07-18 19:16:48 MDT; 30min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 912 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Jul 18 19:16:48 musty systemd[1]: networking.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 18 19:16:48 musty systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Jul 18 19:16:48 musty systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Jul 18 19:16:48 musty systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 18 19:16:48 musty systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 18 19:16:59 musty systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/override.conf:1] Assignment 
Jul 18 19:17:51 musty systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/override.conf:1] Assignment 
Jul 18 19:28:11 musty systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/override.conf:1] Assignment 
Jul 18 19:29:08 musty systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/override.conf:1] Assignment 
Jul 18 19:35:57 musty systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/override.conf:1] Assignment
```

Comment: Also tried systemctl disable networking.service with no effect

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem.

Opened `/etc/init.d/networking` and set `CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=no`

Answer (score 0):

Also check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390307/startup-debian-9-error-failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces

edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:
(remove everything else ..)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Save and reboot