# Slow boot time (Ubuntu 18.04) on SSD

Tags: boot, 18.04, ssd, services, systemd

I've come back to Ubuntu;  I'm on Dual boot (Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04) on a SSD with no swap partition.
I have a problem. While Windows boot time is just a matter of 3-5s, Ubuntu takes 30-40s.

I've run`systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and this is what I got:

[image: Systemd-analyze blame & critical-chain]

Any idea of what is going on (why these services are taking so much time to run)?

Comment: Please don't use images for terminal output. Instead, copy and paste the output into your question, select it with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: I think you may be comparing apples to oranges my friend. Is fast startup enabled in Windows? If so, it's just reading a hibernation file when you start it rather than actually going through the boot process. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup. I have yet to see a version of Ubuntu (since 12.04) that didn't go through a full boot process faster than Windows.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm going to copy my answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109276/604711), as I believe you might be affected by the same problem I was.*

You seem to be affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1763611

### The fix

In order to fix it you have to modify located here: `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and ensure the value is as follows: `RESUME=none`.

Ensure you apply your settings `sudo update-initramfs -u`

#### After fix improvements

```
systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 2.195s (kernel) + 11.663s (userspace) = 13.858s
graphical.target reached after 11.649s in userspace
```

Before it was around ~50s

#### References

This answer is also located on the bug page but it is also located here:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1013935/604711
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390448

Comment: I have an m.2 hard drive, and this answer, combined with [changing my ethernet interface to `allow-hotplug`](https://askubuntu.com/a/887458/22338) brought my boot time from 45 seconds down to 5.7 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this manifest on two desktops I manage.

This is a kernel related regression, the launchpad bug is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1779827

As a workaround, press keys and/or move the mouse at boot.  This will increase the randomness entropy.

Or running the following command to install rng-tools solves the issue for me:

```
sudo apt install rng-tools
```

From Arch wiki: The rng-tools is a set of utilities related to random number generation in kernel. This is mainly useful to increase the quantity of entropy in kernel to make /dev/random faster.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the graphics driver matter. I solved by using additional drivers for graphics for me it was Nvidia.

goto: software & updates -> choose listed graphics driver -> apply changes

Note: I am using kernel version 4.18.0-25-generic

Answer (score 0):

I switched to LightDM and it worked for me.