# Slow startup 18.04 on an SSD

Tags: boot, 18.04, mount, kubuntu

I've been having a lot of trouble lately with startup time. I'm running Kubuntu 18.04, and startup always takes more than a minute on an SSD.

I have a swapfile set to be used, and it shows up when I run

```
sudo swapon --show
```

I have the blame output here

```
systemd-analyze blame
     34.052s systemd-timesyncd.service
     33.978s systemd-resolved.service
      2.518s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
       676ms dev-sda5.device
       585ms systemd-logind.service
       364ms udisks2.service
       347ms nvidia-persistenced.service
       312ms swapfile.swap
       300ms mpd.service
       223ms upower.service
       188ms NetworkManager.service
       133ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       120ms systemd-modules-load.service
       119ms snapd.service
       107ms systemd-hostnamed.service
        94ms networkd-dispatcher.service
        70ms keyboard-setup.service
        67ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-D653\x2dC926.service
        61ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        55ms accounts-daemon.service
        47ms apport.service
        47ms grub-common.service
        42ms systemd-udevd.service
        39ms systemd-journald.service
        39ms ModemManager.service
        36ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        35ms thermald.service
```

Before it was taking 30s to mount my HDD, but I removed that from my fstab since.

Here's my time to boot

```
systemd-analyze time 
Startup finished in 7.746s (firmware) + 4.859s (loader) + 35.728s (kernel) + 37.950s (userspace) = 1min 26.285s
graphical.target reached after 37.946s in userspace
```

Any idea what I should be doing?

Little update: I rebooted again, and here are my new blames and times

```
systemd-analyze blame
      2.510s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
       961ms dev-sda5.device
       619ms systemd-logind.service
       358ms nvidia-persistenced.service
       348ms swapfile.swap
       262ms udisks2.service
       254ms NetworkManager.service
       223ms upower.service
       185ms mpd.service
       184ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-D653\x2dC926.service
       167ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       154ms systemd-resolved.service
       144ms snapd.service
       128ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       127ms systemd-modules-load.service
       124ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       103ms apparmor.service
        80ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        76ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        74ms grub-common.service
        65ms keyboard-setup.service
        47ms ModemManager.service
        46ms apport.service
        42ms systemd-journald.service
        42ms accounts-daemon.service
        41ms wpa_supplicant.service
        37ms systemd-udevd.service
```

.

```
systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 10.518s (firmware) + 4.899s (loader) + 35.676s (kernel) + 38.337s (userspace) = 1min 29.432s
graphical.target reached after 38.333s in userspace
```

Ok, I set the grub to `noresume`, and here are the new numbers on that reboot.

```
systemd-analyze blame    
     33.853s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-D653\x2dC926.service
      2.543s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.157s dev-sda5.device
       606ms systemd-logind.service
       542ms snapd.service
       385ms dev-loop0.device
       358ms udisks2.service
       358ms nvidia-persistenced.service
       343ms dev-loop1.device
       318ms swapfile.swap
       298ms mpd.service
       286ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       226ms upower.service
       195ms NetworkManager.service
       189ms systemd-resolved.service
       144ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       118ms systemd-modules-load.service
       107ms media-ku\x2dgames.mount
        82ms networkd-dispatcher.service
        72ms systemd-udevd.service
        68ms snap-discord-79.mount
        65ms keyboard-setup.service
        58ms grub-common.service
        54ms ModemManager.service
        52ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        44ms accounts-daemon.service
        39ms apparmor.service
```

.

```
systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 10.680s (firmware) + 3.405s (loader) + 3.226s (kernel) + 38.169s (userspace) = 55.482s
graphical.target reached after 38.165s in userspace
```

Comment: Disadvantage of .run file is that is not specifically configured for Ubuntu. You normally have to run updates (dkms) for every kernel update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrease the boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was my nvidia drivers
I removed my nvidia drivers
Then I added them back again, but using the .run from nvidia
It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

*I want to say that this error was frustrating at first because I didn't knew it was a real bug, and I thought fast booting was a "windows thing", luckily curiosity got the better of me*

You seem to be affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1763611

### The fix

In order to fix it you have to modify located here: `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and ensure the value is as follows: `RESUME=none`.

Ensure you apply your settings `sudo update-initramfs -u`

#### After fix improvements

```
systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 2.195s (kernel) + 11.663s (userspace) = 13.858s
graphical.target reached after 11.649s in userspace
```

Before it was around ~50s

#### References

This answer is also located on the bug page but it is also located here:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1013935/604711
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390448