# Ubuntu 18.04.4 on dell XPS - very slow boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, dell

I have a very slow boot. Here is what I did to try to understand where it might be coming from:

```
>> systemd-analyze time

Startup finished in 7.305s (firmware) + 6.781s (loader) + 6.572s (kernel) + 2min 8.861s (userspace) = 2min 29.521s
graphical.target reached after 2min 8.779s in userspace

>> systemd-analyze blame

      2min 258ms networking.service
      6.017s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      5.071s resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
      4.168s ath10k-delay-load.service
      2.046s postfix@-.service
      1.143s dev-nvme0n1p3.device
      1.002s snapd.service
```

I also tried to inspect

```
>> dmesg
```

And I see the following jumps in time:

```
[   25.407277] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp58s0: link becomes ready
[  129.053090] kauditd_printk_skb: 81 callbacks suppressed
```

and:

```
[  167.590890] audit: type=1400 audit(1590617895.162:102): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/core/9066/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3965 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[  216.258537] pci 0000:03:00.0: [8086:1575] type 00 class 0x088000
```

Here is the full dmesg output: https://pastebin.com/pCLEi56g

Not sure if any of that is related to the long waiting times. Does anyone have any ideas where to look more and what could be the issues? Please let me know what kind of additional information you would need.

Many thanks!

Comment: my google fu tells me to google for :     ubuntu show blame networking.service   which has first match             https://askubuntu.com/questions/837932/at-boot-networking-service-is-incredibly-slow-5-minutes-on-ubuntu-16-10

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/887458/599409