# Networking.service blocking boot for 5min after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade

Since updating from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 it takes 5min to boot.

Below is the output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
  5min 10.512s networking.service                                                                       
  4.265s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
  4.161s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
  3.245s docker.service                                                                           
  2.216s dev-sda6.device                                                                          
  2.139s ifupdown-pre.service                                                                     
  1.618s snapd.service                                                                            
  1.130s nfs-server.service                                                                       
  1.095s tor@default.service                                                                      
  1.037s dev-loop8.device                                                                         
   987ms dev-loop9.device                                                                         
   959ms dev-loop1.device                                                                         
   958ms dev-loop10.device
```

So it seems the networking service is for some reason blocking for 5 minutes. Any ideas how to further debug or fix it?

Comment: Look at /var/log/syslog. Maybe the cause of the delay is being logged. If not, start going through all the "connect automatically" connections in Network Manager. De-select the connection if it's not applicable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/887458/395351

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and change `"auto"` for interfaces to `"allow-hotplug"`